# My question is related to a trigger on opportunity

Tags: apex, trigger

```
trigger TriggerOnOpportunityRelatedToAccount on Opportunity (before insert) {
    Set<Id> accId=new Set<Id>();

    for(Opportunity opp:Trigger.new)
    {
        accId.add(opp.AccountId);
    }
    List<Opportunity> opportunityList=new List<Opportunity>();
    List<Opportunity> newOpportunityList=new List<Opportunity>();
    opportunityList=[select id,name,accountId,stagename from opportunity where AccountId=:accId and stagename!='Closed Won'];
            if(opportunityList.size()>0)
            {
                for(opportunity opp: trigger.new){
                    if(opp.stagename!='Closed Won' ) {
                        opp.addError('You cannot create another opportunity');
                    }
                }
            }
```

It is working for single record but when I try to add bulk of records it is not working.

I have a requirement to show only one open opportunity in a particular account otherwise show an error and if that account has one existing open opportunity the opportunity must not be created.

How can I fix my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to determine which accounts already have opportunities, both in the database and in the trigger:

```
trigger TriggerOnOpportunityRelatedToAccount on Opportunity (after insert) {
    Set<Id> accountsWithOpenOpportunities = new Set<Id>(), opportunityAccounts = new Set<Id>();

    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        // Set.add returns true if the set was modified.
        // So when false, the ID was already in the set.
        if(!record.IsClosed && !opportunityAccounts.add(record.AccountId)) {
            record.AccountId.addError('You may only have one open opportunity on an account.');
        }
    }
    // Get all open opportunities not already in the trigger for accounts in the trigger.
    for(AggregateResult result: [SELECT AccountId FROM Opportunity WHERE IsClosed = false AND AccountId = :opportunityAccounts AND Id != :Trigger.new GROUP BY AccountId]) {
        accountsWithOpenOpportunities.add((Id)result.get('AccountId'));
    }
    // And finally add errors to records with open opportunities.
    for(Opportunity record: Trigger.new) {
        if(!record.IsClosed && accountsWithOpenOpportunities.contains(record.AccountId)) {
            record.AccountId.addError('You may only have one open opportunity on an account.');
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this design isn't perfect, as an opportunity could be re-opened, thus allowing more than one open opportunity. You could use a similar design as listed here to account for that possibility.